# java - highlighting only one field

Tags: java, swing

I want to make my code highlights the square on which I click (this works). I do not know how to do that when you click on another square previous died and lights up a new one. 
How to improve the method mouseClicked?

```
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new App();
    }

    App()
    {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Mouse Hover Demo");
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));
        for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
        {
            jFrame.add(new CustomPanel(i));
        }
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class CustomPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener
    {
        /**
         * 
         */
        boolean isHighlighted;
        int postion;
        int tab[];

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        Border blackBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);

        CustomPanel(int postion)
        {
            this.postion = postion;
            addMouseListener(this);
            setBorder(blackBorder);
            setFocusable(true);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize()
        {
            return new Dimension(50, 50);
        }

        @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {

                System.out.println(this.postion);
                setBackground(Color.black);
        }
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
        @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g. in App class you can have field which is table of CustomPanels (`private CustomPanel[] myCustomPanels` and another field - integer `private int highlightedOne = -1` which will point index of element which is highlighted.

Then in method `mouseClicked` you can do something like that:

```
@Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {

                System.out.println(this.postion);
                if (highlightedOne != -1) 
                    myCustomPanels[highlightedOne].setBackground(Color.white);
                highlightedOne = this.position;
                setBackground(Color.black);
        }
```

Field section:

```
public class App
{

    private CustomPanel[] myCustomPanels = new CustomPanel[25];
    private int highlightedOne = -1;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new App();
    }

    App()
    {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Mouse Hover Demo");
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));
        for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
        {
            CustomPanel toAdd = new CustomPanel(i);
            myCustomPanels[i] = toAdd;
            jFrame.add(toAdd);
        }
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
...
```

Alternatively you can use List instead of table - you don't need then pass size to it on beginning.

Comment: Can you show me exactly how to create these fields?

Comment: Ok, I added `private int highlightedOne;` in class `CustomPanel` and 
`public CustomPanel[] myCustomPanels;` in class `App` it's it does not work and error `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"`

Comment: Ok, but I have a error in `myCustomPanels[i] = toAdd;`  `java.lang.NullPointerException` what is this?

Comment: No, I have this line above `myCustomPanels[i]`

Comment: I've forgot to initialize table. Now it should work.

Comment: Ok, thanks it's works. How it works this line `public CustomPanel[] myCustomPanels = new CustomPanel[25];`?

Comment: You tried to assign to variable (myCustomPanels[i]) which wasn't initialized - that (more or less) means that you've tried to assign something to nothing (null) in memory.

Comment: If your problem is solved you should accept the answer. Thanks.